# Why I can't get Entity Framework Migration to initial state?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have deleted development database, and Migrations folder from project. When running unit test with use my project development database is recreated. I don't understand why running update-database gives me

```
PM> Update-Database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying code-based migrations: [201302201840012_wieleDoWielu].
Applying code-based migration: 201302201840012_wieleDoWielu.
```

Why migration: 201302201840012_wieleDoWielu is remembered ? How Can I delete it? Where is stored?

Best Regards
Przemysław Staniszewski

Comment: Perhaps the __MigrationHistory table in your database? Check the `MigrationId` column. Why do you want to delete this though?

Comment: I test this in this way
1. delete Migration folder
2. run Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force which created folder Migrations
3. delete database
4. run unit test which create database
5. delete from [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]
6. run  Add-Migration -IgnoreChanges 
and get 7. Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201302201810047_InitialCreate, 201302201840012_wieleDoWielu]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

Comment: Did you try 'update-database' before the add-migration. It shouldnt be necessary in your scenario but every time I had this error this fixed it.

Comment: Even steps in http://pawel.sawicz.eu/entity-framework-reseting-migrations/ dosn't work for me.

Comment: If I have clean database with no tables and migration table and migration folder project still remember those two migrations

Comment: Did you delete the entire database?

Comment: if I delete database and Migrations folder and _after_ that try to call Add-Migration with or without  -IgnoreChanges  I will get : Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201302201810047_InitialCreate, 201302201840012_wieleDoWielu]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

Comment: why project remember those two migrations? where are stored if entry database was deleted? Maybe there is another database but where? In (localdb)\v11.0 there is no one. I'm using remote SQL server via tcp/ip for development database.

Comment: I have deleted development database and Migrations folder only have Configuration.cs . After call Add-Migration -IgnoreChanges I still get 

Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201302201810047_InitialCreate, 201302201840012_wieleDoWielu]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

So, there those migration are stored?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a answer. Please recover migration folder and its migrations file (recover to your project). Then follow steps from my theard 
http://pawel.sawicz.eu/entity-framework-reseting-migrations/

1) Update-Database -Targetmigration:0 - it's the key! first 
2) Wipe out tables/migrations (you dont have to delete whole folder) 
3) Add-Migration Initialise 
4) Update-Database

Comment: I just did it from Your article before You write this answer (google :) it dosn't help me

Comment: After Update-Database -Targetmigration:0 all tables are deleted with __MigrationHistory also

Comment: does Update-Database -Targetmigration:0 should delete all tables in database?

Comment: yea. It should delete all tables -Targetmigration:0. But migration (files in Migrations folder stays. So here you have to delete manually)

Comment: Hi

I think the problem was that, if every time I started unit test this one runs with compiled library which has Migration files. So update from project where was no those files takes migration info from database.

I really don't know. At fist computer run at Monday  everything just works fine.

Comment: yea I forgot, rebuild or clean should solve this. Like I said, EF migrations just suck sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands
Sqllocaldb.exe stop V11.0
Sqllocaldb.exe delete V11.0

This should remove the reference. You may have to comment out some of the changes before doing this and then re-instating the changes back into model before doing the migration.

I'm new at this, so hopefully I am understanding your problem, because it sounds like the same one I encountered recently.

A more permanent solution may be to add the following code to your Globel file and replace the  with what you need it to be. The article for this can be found at the link below also:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<PersonContext>());
```

http://ilmatte.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/entity-framework-5-code-first-enabling-migrations-in-a-real-project/