# EF Migration does not update FK on delete constraint in database (new initial migration)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, postgresql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have an existing database and .NET project which I recently just upgraded from RC1 to RTM. Since the switch, I had to create an [new initial migration](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jan/13/Resetting-Entity-Framework-Migrations-to-a-clean-Slate#AWordofWarning) due to some issues with table names. I want all FK constraints to be delete cascade, which appears should be the default behaviour.

If I take a look inside my migration file, everything is "onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade" as expected, but this is not reflected in my postgresql database where everything is "ON DELETE NO ACTION."

A small little breakthrough that I found was that if I use the fluent API to do .OnDelete(DeleteBehaviour.Cascade) and attempt to do another migration, it has no effect. The migration created has zero changes. But if I try doing .OnDelete(DeleteBehaviour.SetNull or anything else), then doing another migration after, it will successfully generate a proper migration with the appropriate changes. This makes me think that somehow EF already thinks the database has everything as cascade, when in reality it doesn't, possibly something I did wrong when creating an new initial migration?

How would I fix this to make all foreign keys to be on delete cascade? Preferably without having to write a fluent api statement for each entity in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-created an initial migration using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15026821.) instead. The method I tried before attempted to preserve the previous database, while this one deletes and recreates it.

Comment: The answer is not their! Link is broken